Quill Html Editor Crashes on iOS When Choosing a Color
I am using the quill_html_editor: ^2.2.8 library for the editor. However, when I select a color from the toolbar, the app crashes on iOS, although it works fine on Android devices.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?
Also, are there any alternative libraries that allow creating a separate toolbar for the editor?
I have tried different downgraded versions of the library, but I still encounter the same error.
